# Seek bar progress Drawable Expand

Tags: android, seekbar

hi   I want to make Custom Seek Bar  which look like this
[image]

and this shape what appear on  Android Studio

but when it run on Phone   it look like this

[image]

and here is My code

in XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:max="10000"
            android:progress="500"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_transperent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

where **@drawable/custom_seekbar**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <rotate>
            <layer-list>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar"/>
            </layer-list>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <layer-list>
                <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_progress"/>
            </layer-list>
            </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and **@drawable/progress_bar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="15dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:color="@color/black"
                android:width="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="100dp"
        android:gravity="left"

        android:drawable="@drawable/test_small">

    </item>
    <item
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:drawable="@drawable/test_meduim">

    </item>
    <item
        android:left="100dp"
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:drawable="@drawable/test_large">

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and **progressbar_progress**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="15dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/red" android:width="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:width="19dp"
        android:height="19dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/test_small">

    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="center"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:width="19dp"
        android:height="19dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/test_meduim">

    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:width="19dp"
        android:height="19dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/test_large">

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

can Any one fix this or tell me what`s wrong cuase I have tried Alot of thing and didnt work
and thnak you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The images are scaled (the `width` and `height` attributes were added in API 23). To avoid this you can include a `<bitmap/>` element.

e.g. replace :

```
<item
    android:width="19dp"
    android:height="19dp"
    android:bottom="25dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/test_small"
    android:gravity="left">

</item>
```

with :

```
<item
    android:bottom="25dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/test_small" />
</item>
```

Notice that the `gravity` attribute is on the `bitmap` element.
The trick is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) :

> All drawable items are scaled to fit the size of the containing View,
>   by default. Thus, placing your images in a layer list at different
>   positions might increase the size of the View and some images scale as
>   appropriate. **To avoid scaling items in the list, use a `<bitmap>`
>   element inside the  element to specify the drawable and define
>   the gravity to something that does not scale, such as "center"**.

Comment: it`s worked Like A magic 
thanks bro ..  I will make it as right answer